# How to call route which is not defined in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing

I am newbie to laravel and i am working on a project and i have a following situation

lets assume my base url is https://example.com

Now i want to pass a slug(argument) after a base url which means https://example.com/xyz something like that, and i need to do this on multiple times in my project

This is what i'd tried but it is not working it says that route is not defined.

```
Route::get('{slug?}', [App\Http\Controllers\UiviewsController::class, 'method1'])->name('method1');

Route::get('/method2/{slug?}', function($slug){
    return redirect()->route('method1', ['slug'=>$slug]);
});
```

And also how can i achieve that on which argument which particular method should be called? for example if i have several other routes similar to above one.

how can i achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

Comment: Have you tried with ```Route::get('method/{slug}', [UiviewsController::class, 'method1'])->name('method1');```? and have you defined your ```method1``` in controller as well?

Comment: please do this command and also put the return answer in your post : 
php artisan route:list 
it will help us answer your question better .

Comment: @Hefaz what you are suggesting i'd done that and your solution works fine but then my url will become like this "https://example.com/method1/anyslug" whereas i want a my url to be like this "https://example.com/anyslug" and also slug should specify which method should be called if i have to create multiple routes which are similar to what i am expecting

Comment: Try to convert parameter value using encrypt, if you don't want to see your parameter. I am not sure how to hide method's name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `fallback` system.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

[Laravel Route fallback official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#fallback-routes)

also, beware:

> The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your
> application.

**Other Option:**

Also, you can define a parameter as below example

```
Route::any('{any}', function(){
    //...
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try php artisan route:cache in your terminal then check it again.